# Javascript Pattern Matching a Matrix

Tags: javascript, regex, matrix, pattern-matching, match

In javascript, I have an array of matrices, each of which are 5x5. Eg:

```
25, 32, 26, 27, 29
01, 22, 15, 17, 99
12, 14, 17, 19, 88
16, 14, 12, 17, 19
02, 08, 09, 18, 19
```

I have a method `findMatches  (a, b, c, d, e)`that takes five number values. The goal is to return a new array of matrices which match any of the following conditions:

At least 4 numbers from the `findMatches (a, b, c, d, e)` method match at least 4 consecutive numbers in any matrix row. Eg. If a matrix row has `22, 23, **29**, 24, 25` it would not match because no set of four numbers from the method are next to each-other (it doesn't matter, however, if the order matches that of the order of the ints provides to the method. It can be a, c, d, e and that's fine.). However, if it were `22, 26, 23, 24` it would match because there are at least four consecutive numbers are from the method. Eg:

```
**22**, 32, 26, 27, 29
**26**, 22, 15, 17, 99
**23**, 14, 17, 19, 88
**24**, 14, 12, 17, 19
  02,   08, 09, 18, 19
```

The same as above but in any matrix column instead of row

```
20, 01, 02,  03,  08
01,*22,*23*,*25*,*24*
12, 14, 17, 19, 88
16, 14, 12, 17, 19
02, 08, 09, 18, 19
```

The same as the last two but diagonally, instead of in a row or column

```
**22**, 32, 26, 27, 29            01, 02, 03,   04,   05
01, **23**, 15, 17, 99            06, 07, 08, **24**, 10
12, 14, **26**, 19, 88            11, 12, **23**, 14, 15
16, 14, 12, **25**, 19            16, **25**, 18, 19, 20
02, 08, 09,   18,   19          **22**, 22,   23, 24, 25
```

No two numbers in any matrix are the same. Eg, there will not be the number `1`more than once in the entire matrix.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this. My first instinct is to sit there and generate all possible matrices to check for matches, but this obviously isn't feasible considering that there are well over a million possible combinations.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't look like a problem for regexes at all.

Comment: Thanks! Tag removed.

Comment: Oh it certainly is! Well. . . . part of it is. I had a solution using arrays, but now I'm deep in regex here. Here's a potential starter for horizontal rows (replace 01, 02, 03, 20 with variables obv) `(01|02|03|20), (?!\1)(01|02|03|20), (?!\1)(?!\2)(01|02|03|20), (?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(01|02|03|20)`.

Comment: I thought it might be...Just wasn't sure how to approach it. Readded the tag. Thank you! @CollinD

Comment: @Jgolden1 I've posted a more robust answer for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: How would the column or diagonal matches be represented in your new matrix? Would every matched set of numbers simply be a row?

Comment: > The goal is to return a new array of matrices which match any of the following conditions: < Looks like it just needs to return the entire matrix if it matches.

Comment: Exactly. @DrazenBjelovuk the goal is if the matrix matches any of those conditions, including the diagonal, I take the whole matrix and add it to a new array that the method will return at the end. (This new array of matrices will contain all matrices that satisfied at least one of the conditions).

Comment: Oh wow, I totally misinterpreted the goal then. I thought you wanted some kind of a new matrix consisting of only the matched sets found in the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-regex approach.

```
var matrix;

function findMatches(a, b, c, d, e) {
    // Rows
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        if (checkMatch(matrix[i], [a, b, c, d, e]))
            return true;
    }

    // Columns
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
        if (checkMatch(getColumn(matrix, i), [a, b, c, d, e]))
            return true;
    }

    // Diagonals
    var diagonalArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < matrix[i].length; x++) {
            if (i === x) {
                diagonalArray.push(matrix[i][x]);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    if (checkMatch(diagonalArray, [a, b, c, d, e]));
        return true;

    var revDiagonalArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < matrix[i].length; x++) {
            if (i === 4 - x) {
                revDiagonalArray.push(matrix[i][x]);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    if (checkMatch(revDiagonalArray, [a, b, c, d, e]));
        return true;

    return false;
}

function getColumn(matrix, columnIndex) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < matrx.length; i++)
        array.push(matrix[i][columnIndex]);
    return array;
}

function checkMatch(array, toMatch) {
    var matchCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (toMatch.indexOf(array[i]) > -1) {
            matchCount++;
            if (matchCount === 4)
                return true;
        }
        else if (i > 0)
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So here's a solution using regex:

First, I'm assuming each matrix is stored in a textual format exactly as you stated (that's important, as the regex may need tweaking otherwise).

We'll use this pattern, (you'll need to substitute in variables for the 01, 02, 03, 20). I'll explain it a bit

```
(01|02|03|20), (?!\1)(01|02|03|20), (?!\1)(?!\2)(01|02|03|20), (?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(01|02|03|20)
```

First we match any of the numbers. Then a comma, and then any number that wasn't the first number.

That `(?!\1)` is doing a couple things. First it does a "negative lookahead assertion" which looks forward without consuming the characters, and it makes sure they do not contain `\1` which is a back reference to our first captured number.

Using this for vertical and diagonal lists is a simple matter, just grab the appropriate row and convert it to a horizontal format, then run the regex on it.

Hope this helps you get started. Feel free to post back with your attempts if you run into a wall.